# iOS HTML5 video player next/prev buttons

Tags: html, ios, iphone, video

Is there a way to access/listen to the previous/next buttons in the iOS HTML5 video player? Ideally I would listen to some sort of a prev and next event and swap out the videos accordingly without the user having to close the video and click my prev/next buttons.

[image: iOS video player]
<sub>(source: [iphonefaq.org](http://www.iphonefaq.org/images/archives/vimeo-html5.jpg))</sub>

I am currently using jwplayer to generate the html5 video and listening to their playlist next/prev listeners don't seem to do the trick. I can always find and attach listeners to the actual `<video>` tag pretty easily though.

Answer (score 1):

If you attach listeners to the video tag itself then when the user hits next and previous then the listeners in the code will put up on those buttons. I am doing something similar with youTube videos. If you hit next it goes to the end of the youtube video and fires a video complete event tag and then I load the next video when that is called, so that the video will one loop without the next button and two the users can hit the buttons. I have not found a way to monitor the buttons in the player on the iphone side, but if I find it I will post that as well since it is important to know both angels if possible.

Funny thing I think I am looking to try and do the same exact thing. I know how to transition the videos to the next without having to leave the fullscreen mode because of using youTube api in the js but I am not able to observe the quicktime player itself and need to for another feature that I would like to work on.

Answer (score 0):

That's the native iOS player which is a thin version of Quicktime. You'll know if it's an HTML5 player when it doesn't transition from the Quicktime player and your page in Safari. How is your movie being embedded?

Comment: iOS doesn't allow 'custom' html5 video players, it forces the quicktime-like player. You tap the video and it opens the fullscreen view shown.

Comment: According to Mark Pilgrim, "If you have multiple <source> elements, iOS will not recognize anything but the first one. Since iOS devices only support H.264+AAC+MP4, this effectively means you must always list your MP4 first. This bug is also fixed in iOS 4.0." (http://diveintohtml5.org/video.html#what-works) The test video at the bottom plays the video, in page, on my iPad.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem and was unable to find a solution using the HTML player. I ended up implementing the video player using MPVideoPlayer Framework and launching it from my web view with a custom URL scheme (AppName:Commnad:Asset). I was then able to use the delegate methods to monitor user interactions. If you would like to see basic implementation, let me know and I can add some code.